# No programs shown after hitting super key

Tags: gnome

Not long updated my system to Ubuntu 22.10 using Gnome 43.1
The system has developed a strange one.
Clicking 'Activities' on the top left I get a blank screen with an empty menu bar at the bottom.
Also pressing the 'super' key is the same.

Any pointers

Comment: An OS cannot"develop" habits like humans do.

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-gnome-desktop
```

... seems to have done the trick.